# How to bind return value to model in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple date time inputs in an angular app.

I want to set the value to now on blur of an input. I have accomplished this in multiple locations using `ng-blur` and calling a function.

The issue is I have multiple inputs and it seems stupid to have multiple functions doing the exact same thing other than which property to update on a model.  What is the better way to handle this.

One other catch is that if there is already data to not update.  Again I have the logic, but just need to know how to pass the model to a function and set the return value to it.

Comment: use a directive that requires `ngModel` controller. Then update model in directive. Simply add an attribute wherever you need this functionality

Comment: use ng-bind to set the model value. please share your code snippet !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function in your controller to set a passed object to the current date/time:

```
$scope.setNow = function(dateObject) {
    if (!dateObject) dateObject = new Date();
}
```

Then in your view, whatever date is being displayed can be passed to the model through whatever event you want to use (ng-blur, ng-click, etc)

```
<div ng-click="setNow(thisDate)">
    {{thisDate | date : 'hh:mm:ss'}}
</div>

<div ng-click="setNow(thisOtherDate)">
    {{thisOtherDate | date : 'hh:mm:ss'}}
</div>

<input type="text" ng-model="Task.StartDate" ng-blur="setNow(Task.StartDate)" >
<input type="text" ng-model="Task.EndDate" ng-blur="setNow(Task.EndDate)" >
```

Comment: @charlietfl, i'm not sure that's true.  It looks like the question is saying it is using 'multiple' functions and they want to use a single function.  That sounds like the difference between a hard-coded function and a generalized function and that the questioner wasn't clear on how to pass the model into the function.

Comment: ok...but that could also mean multiple functions due to multiple controllers

Comment: that's actually how i interpreted it anyway..a service function reference would help there but to me directive makes the most sense

Comment: A reasonable assumption.  Not entirely clear in the question.

Comment: To clarify this is to update a model that has multiple date properties.  IE Task.StartTime,Task.EndTime.  I then will pass the object to a save method in the future.  So I have vm.task.  On the view I have ng-bind="vm.task.StartTime".  I want to have ng-click="setNow(vm.task.StartTime)" and just have it set the time for the object.  Is that possible?

Comment: @LucasF., yes, javascript passes objects by reference, so if the StartTime property is an object, then passing it into the function and letting the function update it should work fine.  If you've set StartTime as a string representation of the date, you can do the same thing by passing the task and the name of the property ('StartTime') and updating task[propertyName] = new Date().  Does that help?

Comment: I have that already and it doesn't work.  I am thinking because StartTime has no data and/or is null there is no reference so the value as cannot be set.  If that is true how would I work around this?

Comment: I got it to work by on focus setting the value to the returned value from the function

`ng-focus="task.StartTime = setNow(task.StartTime)"`

This seems sloppy and dirty, but does what I need it to do.

Comment: @LucasF., that would be true in that case.  Try changing the function to `setNow(task,prop) { if (!task[prop]) task[prop = new Date(); }` and then you can call it with `ng-blur="setNow(task, 'StartTime')"` and `ng-blur="setNow(task,'EndTime')"`

Comment: Cool.  That is just as good (and less complicated).  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use a directive.

```
<input ng-model="myDateField1" my-date-setter>
```

Then your directive:

```
app.directive('myDateSetter', function () {   
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        elem.on('blur', function () {
           if (!elem.val()) ctrl.$setViewValue(new Date());
        });            
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can apply the directive wherever needed.